# Keep the aux, fls and log files or not?

Tags: auxiliary-files

I have a C program generating a .tex file. Then afterwards the C# program runs Pdflatex to compile to pdf and generates an .aux , .fls and a .log file.

The tex file is different (in priciple) each time I run my C# program because of different input values.

Is there an advantage in keeping the aux and/of fls file after each compilation?

Or: are they ever helpfull in new compilations?

Comment: If the doc is different each time there probably no reason to keep it.

Comment: the fls and log file are only of interest if you get errors and want to debug (but then they are useful, so you should be able to retrieve them). If you need the aux-file or not depends on if your document contains anything that actually requires two compilations and needs the info from the aux-file.

Comment: my c# program detects whether or not multiple compilations are necessary ("rerun"in the log file) and then executes them. So I will keep the log. Thnx.

Comment: Note that detecting if a rerun is necessary is rather difficult if you allow for arbitrary packages (maybe you don't), because then a status message that you need to rerun does not necessarily have the word 'rerun' in it. In this case you could consider to run `latexmk` from C# instead of `pdflatex`, then the reruns will be performed automatically (by `latexmk`). Also in the 'simple' case this might be a good idea to make the compilation more robust.

Comment: @marijn: thnx for your input. 
During development/debug I can find out how many reruns are necessary: say maximum N times.
Can't I just force my program to **always** do N reruns during normal operation and be done with it? Then I would not require my customer to install Perl, an extra hurdle in my selling process.....

Comment: Installing Perl is a valid point, you can avoid that by always doing the reruns. However, this would slow down the processing if unnecessary runs are performed.

Comment: @Marijn: indeed. I find comments in latexmk.pl that say that in most cases only 2 runs are necessary, sometimes 3 or 4. latexmk.pl has a safety built in: its max nr of reruns is 5. I find that absence of the words "Rerun" or "Warning" in the log is certain enough.